# GDAL appears to ignore NoDataValue

Tags: gdal

I'm trying to build a mosaic, and I rely on the NoDataValue feature to treat some parts of the image as transparent.
However, it appears that GDAL doesn't work as expected.

I also created a very simple test case using a vrt dataset and gdal_translate - and I get the same results (that is - the 2nd image draws over the 1st image, ignoring "transparent areas")

I have to 100X100 image files with a white marking (different in each file) over black background (black being exactly equal to 0)
I built a simple vrt file:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="100" rasterYSize="100">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">a1.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="100" ySize="100"/>
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="100" ySize="100"/>
      <HideNoDataValue>1</HideNoDataValue>
      <NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">a2.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="100" ySize="100"/>
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="100" ySize="100"/>
      <HideNoDataValue>1</HideNoDataValue>
      <NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

and I run the command:

```
gdal_translate mosaic.vrt mosaic.tif
```

The result is identical to image `a2.tif`, instead of being a combination of `a1.tif` and `a2.tif`

I got the error using gdal 1.8 and 1.9

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer in the [gdal-dev](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GDAL-appears-to-ignore-NoDataValue-td4530362.html) list from **Even Rouault**

Several errors :

1. The `NoDataValue` and `HideNoDataValue` elements are only valid under the  `VRTRasterBand` element, not `SimpleSource`
2. You want to change `SimpleSource` to `ComplexSource`, and add a `<NODATA>0</NODATA>` element in it. (well basically rename your current  `NoDataValue` to `NODATA`.

Comment: Hi. I edited your post because the `<NODATA>0</NODATA>` part was missing. Anyway, is it possible to take a look at your final `vrt`? I tried with several combinations of `HideNoData`, `NoDataValue` and `NODATA` but nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have access to these files anymore.